# Matplotlib error

Tags: matplotlib

I was trying this simple code and am unable to find the error I made in it.

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = ['Python','C++','Java','Pearl','Lisp']
y = [10,8,6,4,2,1]
plt.bar(x, y,align='edge',color='orange')
plt.show()
```

And I am getting the error:

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're giving `x` with a shape of `(5,)` and `y` with a shape of `(6,)`. Removing the last item from `y` to make them of equal length works without an error:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = ['Python', 'C++', 'Java', 'Perl', 'Lisp']
y = [10, 8, 6, 4, 2]

plt.bar(x, y, align='edge', color='orange')
plt.show()
```

[image]